# How can I import/remove an event on macbook calendar using .ics file

Tags: icalendar

Ho can I remove existing even from my mac book which was imported by .ics file. My problem is that when I import a new event with .ics all is good, but when I want to remove same one with .ics it doesn't remove an from calendar.

This is an example of .ics file with "Confirmed" status:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Test Ltd//Test 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20190430T101846Z
DTSTART:20190430T121700Z
DTEND:20190430T124700Z
SEQUENCE:0
UID:fb51bdc8-d0bd-4a10-a64c-8c15e7968cc1
TZID:Asia/Yerevan
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This is an example for .ics file with "Cancelled" status:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Test Ltd//Test 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20190430T101924Z
DTSTART:20190430T121700Z
DTEND:20190430T124700Z
SEQUENCE:1
UID:fb51bdc8-d0bd-4a10-a64c-8c15e7968cc1
TZID:Asia/Yerevan
STATUS:CANCELLED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Not too sure that this is possible. But this isn't really a programming question. Another way of doing this - which might work for you. Is produce a url which the user can add to their calendar and then you have a system which can modify the events within.

Comment: I am making this ICS by Java, so need to know what I am missing inside which will solve the problem

Comment: Well had a look and looks like I might be wrong.
What you have should work 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551764/how-to-cancel-an-calendar-event-using-ics-files/10561761

Comment: Similar issues with apple https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2589905 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3200468?page=2 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6560268 keeps coming up.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70768/why-wont-ical-delete-meetings-when-im-sent-a-cancellation-notice it goes on.....

Comment: But perhaps... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227488/why-is-my-ics-file-not-registering-a-cancel-event-when-it-is-opened

Comment: Thank you @RichardHousham, your answers are very useful. So what I can see is that apple doesn't support event cancellation , there is no even answer in apple.com discussions

Comment: No worries. Seems a bit lame of apple. Especially given that this seems pretty standard for most calendars and is part of the ics standard. Apple seem to have a problem with Status in general. I think your solution is just just try and amend the title to CANCELLED - or something.